# Unable to loop through data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api, ampscript, dataextensions

For some reason I'm having trouble looping through records in my sample DE. I have three records being stored in the DE and I'm trying to loop the HTML Table three times to print all of the fields from the data extension.

My AMPscript passes validation but errors when I generate a preview send. My error message and AMPscript are posted below. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks everybody.

**Error Message:**
[image]

**AMPscript Code:**

```
%%[
  var @nmaratasDE, @rsRow, @i, @email_address, @first_name, @last_name, @address, @city, @state, @zip, @language
  SET @nmaratasDE = LookupRows("nmaratasDE")

  IF RowCount(@nmaratasDE) > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@nmaratasDE) DO
      SET @rsRow = Field(Row(@nmaratasDE, @i))
      SET @email_address = Field(@rsRow, "email_address")
      SET @first_name = Field(@rsRow, "first_name")
      SET @last_name = Field(@rsRow, "last_name")
      SET @address = Field(@rsRow, "address")
      SET @city = Field(@rsRow, "city")
      SET @state = Field(@rsRow, "state")
      SET @zip = Field(@rsRow, "zip")
      SET @language = Field(@rsRow, "language")
      ]%%
      <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; max-width:650px; padding:10px; display:block; border:1px dashed red;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong>Email Address: </strong> %%=v(@email_address)=%%<br>
            <strong>First Name: </strong> %%=v(@first_name)=%%<br>
            <strong>Last Name: </strong> %%=v(@last_name)=%%<br>
            <strong>Address: </strong> %%=v(@address)=%%<br>
            <strong>City: </strong> %%=v(@city)=%%<br>
            <strong>State: </strong> %%=v(@state)=%%<br>
            <strong>Zip: </strong> %%=v(@zip)=%%<br>
            <strong>Language: </strong> %%=v(@language)=%%
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      %%[
      NEXT  @i
  ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some fields in your [lookupRows()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupRows) function.  You'll need to specify some sort of lookup field and a matching value.  Sometimes I'll add a `lookupKey` column to DE and set a default value to "1" and then use that as my lookup value.

```
 %%[
      var @nmaratasDE, @rsRow, @i, @email_address, @first_name, @last_name, @address, @city, @state, @zip, @language

      var @lookupValue
      set @lookupValue = "whee"

      set @nmaratasDE = LookupRows("nmaratasDE","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)

      IF RowCount(@nmaratasDE) > 0 THEN
        FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@nmaratasDE) DO
          SET @rsRow = Row(@nmaratasDE, @i)
          SET @email_address = Field(@rsRow, "email_address")
          SET @first_name = Field(@rsRow, "first_name")
          SET @last_name = Field(@rsRow, "last_name")
          SET @address = Field(@rsRow, "address")
          SET @city = Field(@rsRow, "city")
          SET @state = Field(@rsRow, "state")
          SET @zip = Field(@rsRow, "zip")
          SET @language = Field(@rsRow, "language")
          ]%%
          <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; max-width:650px; padding:10px; display:block; border:1px dashed red;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <strong>Email Address: </strong> %%=v(@email_address)=%%<br>
                <strong>First Name: </strong> %%=v(@first_name)=%%<br>
                <strong>Last Name: </strong> %%=v(@last_name)=%%<br>
                <strong>Address: </strong> %%=v(@address)=%%<br>
                <strong>City: </strong> %%=v(@city)=%%<br>
                <strong>State: </strong> %%=v(@state)=%%<br>
                <strong>Zip: </strong> %%=v(@zip)=%%<br>
                <strong>Language: </strong> %%=v(@language)=%%
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          %%[
          NEXT  @i
      ENDIF
    ]%%
```

Also, there are a lot more people answering SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) -- mostly tagged with [marketing-cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud), [ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript), and [soap-api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soap-api).

Comment: Hey thanks for your help Adam. I didn't realize my LookupRows was written incorrectly. I went ahead and made those AMPscript changes and added an additional column to my DE called **lookup_key** and assigned a default text value of 1 to each of my records. But for some reason when I generate preview I keep getting the same error. It's really strange...

Comment: I see the issue -- `SET @rsRow = Field(Row(@nmaratasDE, @i))` should be `SET @rsRow = Row(@nmaratasDE, @i)`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for commenting back so fast. Alright I just tried that also and still no dice. This is the weirdest thing ever, I've never had so much trouble writing a for loop before lol.

Comment: I'd take out all of the fields but one and add them back one at a time.

Comment: ahh that's a good idea I'm going to give that a shot and see what happens. Hey thanks for all your help man I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Question Answer**

With the help of a colleague I was able to figure this out. The answer is below. Thank you to everyone that helped.

```
%%[
    var @lookupValue
    var @nmaratasDE
    var @i
    var @rowCount

    set @lookupValue = "1"
    set @nmaratasDE = lookupRows("nmaratasDE","lookup_key", @lookupValue)
    for @i = 1 to rowCount(@nmaratasDE) do
      set @rowCount = row(@nmaratasDE,@i)
      ]%%
      <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; max-width:650px; padding:10px; display:block; border:1px dashed red;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong>Email Address: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"email_address")=%%<br>
            <strong>First Name: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"first_name")=%%<br>
            <strong>Last Name: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"last_name")=%%<br>
            <strong>Address: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"address")=%%<br>
            <strong>City: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"city")=%%<br>
            <strong>State: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"state")=%%<br>
            <strong>Zip: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"zip")=%%<br>
            <strong>Language: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"language")=%%
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      %%[
      next @i
]%%
```